# cd out of deleted folder

Tags: bash, command-line, cd-command, deleted-files

Is there a way to `cd` out of a directory which has just been deleted (go up one level into the upper folder which still exists?

It often happens to me that I have a console opened for a folder, and then I delete the folder with my temporary test data and create another one.

However, both `cd ..` and `cd $(pwd)/..` only get me to the trash bin, and not to the upper directory when I try to leave the deleted folder.

So, current situation is:

```
$ mkdir -p /home/me/test/p1
$ cd /home/me/test/p1
```

now I delete the folder p1

```
$ cd ..
me:~/.local/share/Trash/files$ ...
```

I'm now searching for a way to get into `/home/me/test/` and not into the Trash bin. Is there such a command?

Comment: Note: you should use `$PWD` and not `$(pwd)`.  Bash keeps track of *names* of directories in PWD. Instead the command `pwd` gives the current working directory (so it moves with directory moving or symlinks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PWD variable hold current path definition.

to go up one level

```
cd $(dirname $PWD)
```

will expand to

```
cd $(dirname /home/me/foo/bar/baz/deleteddirectory)
```

who expand to

```
cd /home/me/foo/bar/baz/
```

this supposed you delete only one level of dir.

Comment: For me, `basename /home/me/foo/bar/baz/deleteddirectory` expands to `deleteddirectory` and not to `/home/me/foo/bar/baz`

Comment: I found `dirname` which seems to do what I want to - `cd $(dirname $PWD)` gets me out of the deleted folder.

Answer (score 0):

The shell stores the path to the current working directory in the variable `PWD`. Unless configured otherwise, that's the path as specified to the shell, even if the directory has been moved or if symbolic links are involved. So you can use this to change to the apparent parent of the directory, even if the actual location of the directory is different. E.g. `cd /foo/bar` sets `PWD` to `/foo/bar` even if `bar` is a symbolic link (`cd -P` makes the shell resolve the symbolic link instead) and `PWD` remains set even if the directory is then moved or deleted.

Thus you can change to the apparent parent directory by taking `PWD` and stripping off the part after the last slash:

```
cd ${PWD%/*}
```

If there are whitespace or wildcards in the path to the directory then you need quotes:

```
cd "${PWD%/*}"
```

In zsh this can be abbreviated to

```
cd $PWD:h
```

You can also use the longer but perhaps more memorable

```
cd "$(dirname "$PWD")"
```

(double quotes not needed if no whitespace or wildcards are in the directory name).